# Heres some async code to provide a queue for amazon searches with selenium, why am i getting AttributeError? The __init__ is not running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributeerror, init

Here is the code I am using to search amazon from my tornado web app. At the moment I only have one of these classes (and one webdriver) instantiated. I may want a pool of them in the future (yes i know there is selenum grid, but that's not my question.) My question is, why is the __init__ apparently not running? Why is there an attributeError for accessing the self.queue var which is clearly defined in the __init__?

```
import asyncio
import uuid
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


class Searcher:
    def __init___(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/felix/project/geckodriver")
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        self.driver.get("https://amazon.com/")
        self.queue = []

    async def _search(self, query):
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "twotabsearchtextbox").send_keys("pixel" + Keys.RETURN)
        self.wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                "//div[contains(@class, 'sg-col-inner')]/div[contains(@class, 'a-section')]"
                "/div[contains(@class, 'a-section')]")))
        el = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                "//div[contains(@class, 'a-section')]/div[h2][not(contains(.,'Sponsored'))]"
                "[contains(@class, 'a-section')]/..")
        out=[]
        for e in range(len(el)):
            try:
                out+=[{"price": el[e].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[contains(@class, 'a-price-whole')]").text + "." +
                el[e].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[contains(@class, 'a-price-fraction')]").text,
                "title": el[e].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//h2").text}]
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
        return out

    def search(self, query):
        _id = uuid.uuid4()
        self.queue.append(_id)
        async def help(self):
            while 1:
                if _id == self.queue[0]:
                    return await self._search(query)
                await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        res = help(self)
        self.queue.pop()
        return res

a = Searcher()
print(asyncio.run(a.search("test")))
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/felix/project/search.py", line 49, in <module>
    print(asyncio.run(a.search("test")))
  File "/home/felix/project/search.py", line 38, in search
    self.queue.append(_id)
AttributeError: 'Searcher' object has no attribute 'queue'
```

Comment: It's best to avoid putting complex code that does IO in the `__init__`, anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure what code you are referring to, or why you wouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

How rediciulous... I had named the __init__ function __init___.

I've fixed other bugs refactored and here's the working code

```
import asyncio
import uuid
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


class Searcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/felix/amcoin/geckodriver")
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        self.driver.get("https://amazon.com/")
        self.queue = []

    async def _search(self, query):
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "twotabsearchtextbox").send_keys(query + Keys.RETURN)
        self.wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                "//div[contains(@class, 'sg-col-inner')]/div[contains(@class, 'a-section')]"
                "/div[contains(@class, 'a-section')]")))
        el = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                "//div[contains(@class, 'a-section')]/div[h2][not(contains(.,'Sponsored'))]"
                "[contains(@class, 'a-section')]/..")
        out=[]
        for e in range(len(el)):
            try:
                out+=[{"price": el[e].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[contains(@class, 'a-price-whole')]").text + "." +
                el[e].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[contains(@class, 'a-price-fraction')]").text,
                "title": el[e].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//h2").text}]
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
        return out

    async def search(self, query):
        _id = uuid.uuid4()
        self.queue.append(_id)
        while 1:
            if _id == self.queue[0]:
                res = await self._search(query)
                self.queue.pop()
                return res
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

a = Searcher()
print(asyncio.run(a.search("test")))
```